# Obtain row information when click a button inside a listVIew

Tags: android

I have a ListView that contains some information that i retrieve from a DB. I display all the information correctly in the list and i added a button that appear in each row.
When I click on this button i need to perform some operations whit the specific data of the row (change a flag for the record in the DB).

This is my custom adaptar code:

```
    public class AdapterAprobacion extends ArrayAdapter<Transaccion>{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public List<Transacciones> Transacciones;

    public AdapterAprobacion(Activity activity, List<Transacciones> Transacciones){
        super(activity, R.layout.lista_notificaciones, Transacciones);
        this.Transacciones=Transacciones;


    inflater = activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){

        final Transaccion Transacciones= Transacciones.get(position);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_notificaciones, parent, false);


        TextView Header=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTitulo);
        Header.setText(Transacciones.getTitle());

        ImageView Categoria=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageProfile);

         TextView descripcion=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescripcion);
         descripcion.setText(Transacciones.getBody());

        final ImageButton btnApprove=(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgApprove);

        btnApprove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }

   }
```

I suppose that i have to use the onClickListener on the getView Method but the problem is that i don't know how to use the parameters of the specific clicked row.

Thanks!

Comment: you are doing fine just write code which will change the flag in the database in onClick(View v){}

Comment: you have List<Transacciones> right. Do you want to change these object data right?

Comment: A listview uses onitemclicklistner not onclicklistner

Comment: I need to know which object on the list i clicked. If i do soemthing like a toast to show lets say the Header it doesn't work because i don't know how to reference the position of the row

Answer (score 1):

You should use "viewholder" pattern

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_notificaciones, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.btnApprove=(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgApprove);
        btnApprove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageButton btnApprove;
}
```

Add into `ViewHolder` required data

Comment: It should be a comment not an answer

Comment: sorry for that, I accidentally posted not complete answer

Answer (score 0):

you can get position when you click corresponding button, with position you can get row data.

```
convertView.btnApprove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           Toast.makeText(context, position + " clicked" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTag to the button.

```
button.setTag(object);
```

and inside onClick(), retrieve the Tag:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Object tag = v.getTag();
}
```

What i would do is, save any unique Id of the row or position of the row in the Tag. And get the unique Id/ position after onClick(). You can save any object to the Tag , which will be useful to determine the row after onClick().

Answer (score 0):

You can `btnApprove.setTag( <object/position> )` to button and in onclick:

```
btnApprove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           <typecast object/position >  = v.getTag();
           //perform operation on object/position
        }
    });
```

That's the easiest way, please don't set object if its too large, I would personally use position and get object of that position.